# Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5932143-0 FOUND

Tags: google-chrome, clamav, trojan

I am scanning Ubuntu 14.04 by clamav

```
~$ sudo clamscan --max-filesize=3999M --max-scansize=3999M --exclude-dir=/sys/* -i -r /

/opt/google/chrome/chrome: Unix.Trojan.Mirai-5932143-0 FOUND
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome, in-spite I am receiving the Trojan.Mirai warning.

What should I do?

Comment: Probably a false positive from what I could find on the net. Test the file in question on https://www.virustotal.com/

Comment: It says the file is clean.

Comment: Then it is a false positive, nothing to worry about. Clamscan isnt the best anyways and even the best scanners produce false positives from time to time.

Comment: @Videonauth Can you suggest which one is best?

Comment: I'am aswell using clamscan and then if it finds something verify the find on virustotal. there are a few out there but which one is bet, not sure. Most of them want to have an intensive grip on the system.